# xQuery - BFS to find all paths between two nodes

Tags: xquery, breadth-first-search, exist-db, xquery-3.0

I've asked a question 2 months or so where i needed help implementing the BFS algorithm in xquery to find the shortest path between two nodes in a directed graph, luckily someone helped me and the code they gave me worked with some minor modifications.

The thing now is that testing the whole program i came to the conclusion that i need to find all paths between two nodes. The code i have as of now is:

```
declare function local:result($steps, $dest) {
let $pred := 
for $node in $steps
return if($node/@to = $dest)then string($node/@from) else ()
return if(exists($pred)) then (local:result($steps, $pred), $dest)
else $dest
};

declare function local:BFS($graph, $start, $end) {
local:BFS($graph, $start, <edge to="{$start}" />, $end, 1)
};

declare function local:BFS($graph, $queue, $steps, $end, $iteracion) {
if(empty($queue)) then error(xs:QName('local:NOTFOUND'), $iteracion)
else (
  let $curr := $queue[1], $rest-queue := $queue[position() > 1]
  return (
     if($curr eq $end) then local:result($steps, $end)
     else (
        let $successors :=  if (empty($graph)) then error(xs:QName('local:NOTFOUND'), 'no grafo') else 
        for $node in $graph/Enlaces/Enlace/origen
        return if(string($node) = $curr) then $graph[Enlaces/Enlace/origen/text() = $node]/id/text() else  ()
        let $new-steps  := 
        for $succ in $successors
          return <edge from="{$curr}" to="{$succ}" />
        return local:BFS( $graph,($rest-queue, $successors),($steps, $new-steps),$end, $iteracion + 1)
  )
)
)};
```

The code as it is, is working but only finds the shortest path between two nodes, it even finds several paths when their lengths are the same but i need it to find all possible paths.

so my question is how do i modify the given code to find all paths? or i could even accept another algorithm like DFS which i know how to implement in other languages but i don't know how to translate it to xQuery

I'm not proficient in xQuery nor functional programming so that's why i don't do it by myself although i tried.

EDIT:

A Sample input for this program would be a graph such as

```
<node>
  <id> 123-456-789</id>
  <name> something </name>
  <Links>
     <Link>
        <origin></origin>
     </Link>
  <Links/>

 <node>
  <id> 245-678-901</id>
  <name> node 2</name>
  <Links>
     <Link>
        <origin> 123-456-789 </origin>
     </Link>
  <Links/>

  <node>
  <id> xxx-xxx-xxx</id>
  <name> node 3</name>
  <Links>
     <Link>
        <origin> 123-456-789 </origin>
     </Link>
  <Links>

  <node>
  <id> 234-546-768</id>
  <name> node 4</name>
  <Links>
     <Link>
        <origin> 245-678-901</origin>
     </Link>
  <Links/>
```

then if i call the function on the first node it would have to return all subsequent nodes as the first node is the 'root' in this example but if i call the function on node 2 it would have to return node 4 as it's origin is node 2

Comment: If your graph contains cycles, there can be an infinite number of paths between two nodes (you can go through the cycle as often as you want). Are you only interested in [simple paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_path)?

Comment: Yes, it is not needed to solve the problem for cycles, just simple paths.

Comment: some sample input would help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all paths you might as well use DFS:

```
<nodes>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <edges>
      <edge to="2"/>
      <edge to="5"/>
    </edges>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <edges>
      <edge to="3"/>
      <edge to="1"/>
    </edges>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>3</id>
    <edges/>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>5</id>
    <edges>
      <edge to="3"/>
      <edge to="4"/>
    </edges>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>4</id>
    <edges>
      <edge to="3"/>
    </edges>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

Then use this

```
declare function local:DFS($graph, $visited as xs:string*, $start, $end) {
  if ($start/id = $end/id) then (string-join($visited, '->')) else (
  for $edge in $start//edge
    return if (not($visited = $edge/@to)) then (local:DFS($graph, ($visited, data($edge/@to)), $graph//node[id = $edge/@to], $end)) else ())
};

declare function local:DFS($graph, $start, $end) {
  local:DFS($graph, ($start/id/text()), $start, $end)
};

local:DFS(., //node[id='1'], //node[id='3'])
```

Comment: I will try your answer as soon as i can and mark it if it works for me, also i'll give you the reputation.You might see my edit as well for the sample input if it matters